# URLrewriting - Multiple same shortcuts from unique domains

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

I have an Umbraco site and am using URLrewritning.net

I have two distinct issues:

1. I have multiple domains on the site where Users will type foo.com and will need to go to foo.com/Home/Branding?brand=123 and go to baz.com and go to foo.com/Home/Branding?brand=456 - where the domain will need to change. How do I setup multiple domains that will end up forwarding to the primary domain?
2. Once I get past that, the unique domains have multiple same shortcuts: 
   A user will type www.foo.com/shortcut and need to go here:  foo.com/brands/foo/abc.aspx  and a user will type www.baz.com/shortcut and go to here: foo.com/brands/foo/cdf.aspx - so it will take the user to the primary domain

Comment: Read any tutorial on mod_rewrite. For changing domain, you will use [R] (redirect) so that the user's browser will make a new connection to the other domain.

Comment: I don't think the topic starter has any use of mod_rewrite because Umbraco is Windows based (uses URLrewriting.net to do rewriting, not Apaches mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco uses the standard functionality of URLRewriting.net to perform rewrites. So to perform your actions you can do:

1:

- Point the domains to the right IP in the DNS.
- Create appropriate host headers in IIS

1 and 2:

- In the Umbraco folder "config" there is a file UrlRewriting.config.
  Here you can define your own rewrite rules to do any possible rewrite.
- Follow the instructions on the module URL Rewriting.net from: 
  http://www.urlrewriting.net/160/en/documentation.html to add a couple of rewrite rules.
  You can use complete URL's and redirect to another url in a rule. Just be sure to add Redirect="domain" for this.
  i.e.:

> ```
> <add name="redirect" virtualUrl="^http\://www.domain1.com/page.aspx" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="http://www.domain2.com/page2.aspx" redirect="Domain" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true" /></li>
> ```